# Is PRIMARY(ColumnA, ColumnB) + INDEX(ColumnB) + PARTITIONING(ColumnB) redundant?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, partitioning, index-tuning

I have a big table (30 millions rows) defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `drawing` ( 
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL, 
`artist` int unsigned NOT NULL, 
`imageUrl` text NOT NULL,
`uploadDate` timestamp NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`uploadDate`), 
KEY `uploadDate` (`uploadDate`),
KEY `artist` (`artist`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED /*!50100
PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(uploadDate)) (
    PARTITION up2009 VALUES LESS THAN (1262304000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2010 VALUES LESS THAN (1293840000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2011 VALUES LESS THAN (1325376000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2012 VALUES LESS THAN (1356998400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2013 VALUES LESS THAN (1388534400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2014 VALUES LESS THAN (1420070400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2015 VALUES LESS THAN (1451606400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2016 VALUES LESS THAN (1483228800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2017 VALUES LESS THAN (1514764800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2018 VALUES LESS THAN (1546300800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2019 VALUES LESS THAN (1577836800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2020 VALUES LESS THAN (1609459200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION up2021 VALUES LESS THAN (1640995200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION upNew VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

As you see:

- Table is partitioned based on the value of `uploadDate`, per year. Since there are lots of rows, I've found it useful when filtering by date (that is a typical operation in our DB). Speed of filtering increased significantly.
- Since the partition is based on `uploadDate`, and we have also the identifier `id`, the primary key must be composed by both `id` + `uploadDate`

Sometimes we also perform filtering by `artist`, then sorting on `uploadDate`. No performances issues here.

Instead, we've found INSERT operations very slow.

**Question**: is it still useful to have an index on just (`uploadDate`)?

Comment: *is it still useful to have an index on just (uploadDate)?* If index exists, it can be used. If no index, fullscan by at list a partition primary key will be used.

Comment: Well, I'm focusing on the current amount of data and indexes that we need, and it is probably the cause of slow INSERTs. The correct question is "do I have slowdowns in sortings if I remove it and rely only in (id,uploadDate) key?"

Comment: Look `EXPLAIN`. Then edit the query by adding `IGNORE INDEX` and look again.

Comment: Show us the queries; partitioning is often of no use.

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITIONing` is not a performance panacea.

For

```
WHERE artist = 'constant'
  AND uploadDate BETWEEN ...
```

`INDEX(artist, uploadDate)` on a non-partitioned table is as good (or better) than using partitioning.

Do you have other queries?  So far you have not presented a convincing case for partitioning.

Will you be purging 'old' data?  Being able to use `DROP PARTITION` instead of `DELETE` is one of the *few* benefits of `PARTITION BY RANGE`.

[*More Discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)